# Adding date to new columns returns error

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs

I'm trying to add a new column to my file. I want to add the date to each row of my file.

Filename is: 2016-06-15.txt

The schema my file is:

```
A  B  C
7  8  13
```

I want to obtain:

```
Date        A  B  C
2016-06-15  7  8  13
```

For that I'm using Pig with following script:

```
A = LOAD 'user/cloudera/Analytics/source/file.txt' using PigStorage(' ','-tagPath');
DUMP A ;   ****--> ERROR****
STORE A INTO 'user/cloudera/Analytics/source/file.txt' USING PigStorage(' ');  ****--> ERROR****
```

But I'm getting an error and I don't have any log available :( Anyone can help? Many thanks!

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the -tagFile option to get the file name as the first field.
Before that check to make sure the file path is correct.Looks like a forward slash is missing at the beginning of your file path.Ensure you are using the correct delimiter in PigStorage.Seems like the columns are separated by a tab or multiple spaces.Lastly choose a different folder to Store the new file or else you will get a file exists error.

```
A = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Analytics/source/2016-06-15.txt' using PigStorage(' ','-tagFile');
STORE A INTO '/user/cloudera/Analytics/NEW_source/2016-06-15.txt' USING PigStorage(' ');
```

Comment: Store statement will create it at the location and format you specify.

Comment: thanks inquisitive_mind :) It returns what I want :D Many thanks!

Just one more question: This divide the txt file into 2 text files, is possible to aggregate into one on same script?

Comment: No, I do not think so.